# Speeding up Scapy scans?

Tags: python, scapy

I'm writing a port scanner using scapy, but I'm finding that it is horrendously slow.  I use a single line of code to actually do the scan:

```
ans, unans = sr(IP(dst=targetIP)/TCP(dport=(1, 49151), flags='S'))
```

And it takes about 15 minutes to run, even though I'm on the same LAN as the computer I'm scanning.  Heck, I'm plugged into the same SWITCH as my target!

I tried multi-threading, but that actually made it *slower*.  Using multiple processes is faster, but only to a certain point.  Either scapy's sniffer can't keep up and it is losing packets, or the network itself is dropping packets (Not likely, considering nmap works fine).  In either case, using 5 processes, I got the TCP scan time down to about 5-6 minutes, which while is 1/3rd the time it takes to run it in a single process, is still much slower than the ~10 seconds nmap takes.

Anyone know any other tricks to speed up Scapy port scans of large ranges?

Comment: Why can't you just use nmap to run your scans?

Comment: Is your nmap scan actually testing all 49151 ports, or just the well-known subset? 49151 ports in 15 minutes averages out to 18ms per attempt. That's a little slow for a LAN but not radically so. What's your ping time to the target?

Comment: @RyPeck: To be honest, I'm not sure.  It's just what my boss has asked for.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: About 0.25-0.3 ms.  Testing all 49151 ports.  As I mentioned though, nmap scans all 49151 ports in under 30 seconds.

Comment: Try this: https://home.regit.org/2014/04/speeding-up-scapy-packets-sending/

Answer (score 1):

Note that in your example, you had forgotten the `timeout` parameter, which is crucial: without it, scapy will wait to have recieved an answer for each packet you have send, which in your case will never happend !

As of 2018 (2.3.3dev (github version)), running

```
ans, unans = sr(IP(dst=targetIP)/TCP(dport=(1, 49151), flags='S', timeout=2))
```

Takes approximately 90 sec. The pending PR https://github.com/secdev/scapy/pull/1142 speed that up to around 50sec.